# How to include ' ' in MySQL Prepared Statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure, with a prepared statement where I need to insert `' '` in one of the column data. Here is my Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `manage_page`(IN `actionType` VARCHAR(100), IN `actionValue` TEXT)
BEGIN
###########################################################
if(actionType='showDetails') then
 SET @P_DEPT = '
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalGPCandidates FROM user_mstr WHERE User_DeletedFlag=false';
         SET @P_DEPT = concat(@P_DEPT,' and Gender= "Female"');
        PREPARE STMT FROM @P_DEPT;
        EXECUTE STMT;  
end if;


END
```

But I am getting 0 even if there are 12 Female Users.

Comment: Why are you composing this in two parts? You need a space on that `CONCAT()` call or you get `falseand`.

Comment: This would be better as a `VIEW` than as some kind of stored procedure. It's really just `SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountByGender, Gender WHERE User_DeletedFlag=false GROUP BY Gender`.

Comment: @tadman The problem is, I am getting 0 as total number of Female Candidates. I want to know if there is any syntax error

Comment: and using `View` would be illogical because there are certain things here in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure what's "illogical" about it, as that's what views are for: Storing canned queries. What you have here looks like application code that's leaked into the database.

Comment: Run the query outside of the stored procedure. Run it with and without that `DeletedFlag` test. How are you calling this?

Comment: @tadman Using Views could be illogical because theer a re a lot of data which are called in out company standards, and which are all called using stored procedures.

Comment: I shoud be getting 10 as output, but nothing while calling from Laravel Controller

Comment: Oh, you have one of *those* DBAs that insists on this sort of baroque access. In that case, I guess you're stuck, which is a shame. Running this as a plain query is *way* easier, especially through Laravel's Eloquent layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape them :

```
 SET @P_DEPT = '
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalGPCandidates FROM user_mstr WHERE User_DeletedFlag=false';
     SET @P_DEPT = concat(@P_DEPT,' and Gender= \'Female\'');
 -- test the returned query
 select @P_DEPT ;
```

Your second set is actually useless while you can add this condition straight into the first one.